# Confirming understanding of multiprocessing module and how threads are started

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hi I am unsure of whether I am understanding the multiprocessing module and wanted to seek advice. I was reviewing the Painless Concurrency examples found here http://revista.python.org.ar/1/html-en/PET-1-processing.pdf. Below is the code I am testing.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

x = 4
y = 6

def f1(x,y):

    x = x+y
    print 'F1:', x


def f2(x,y):
    y = x-y
    print 'F2:', y


def main():
    print "Starting main program"
    hilo1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f1, args=(x,y))
    hilo2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f2, args=(x,y))
    print "Launching threads"
    hilo1.start()
    hilo2.start()
    hilo1.join()
    hilo2.join()
    print "Both threads finished"
    print "Ending program"
    print "X:", x, "Y:", y


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The output is:

```
Starting main program
Launching threads
Both threads finished
Ending program
X: 4 Y: 6
```

I was expecting something closer to:

```
Starting main program
Launching threads
F1: 10
F2: -2
Both threads finished
Ending program
X: 4 Y: 6
```

which is the output when I change main() to:

```
def main():
    print "Starting main program"
    hilo1 = f1(x,y)
    hilo2 = f2(x,y)
    print "Launching threads"
    print "Both threads finished"
    print "Ending program"
    print "X:", x, "Y:", y
```

Is the multiprocessing thread running? What would be the best way to check that each function is run using multiprocessing?

Comment: What environment are you running the script in? CLI? IDLE? When I run this via the CLI, it outputs exactly what you were expecting it to output. I suspect whatever you're using to launch to run the script is losing the output from the sub-processes.

Comment: I am running the script in IDLE. Do you have any suggestions to not lose the output from the sub-processes?

Comment: Your mistake is believing these are threads when they are actually processes. Processes don't share as much as threads, e.g. output devices might not be inherited.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for the info. I was able to use the threading module instead of the multiprocessing module to get the desired result. I will need to read up on the differences between the two